# Appending feature classes from one geodatabase to another geodatabase for python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, append, error-000338

I am attempting to write a stand alone python script which will loop through the first GDB and append each feature class to its corresponding feature class in the second GDB.  The error code that I keep getting is:

> "ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.  ERROR
>   000338: Inputs must be either all Feature Classes, Tables or Rasters;
>   not mixed.  Failed to execute (Append)."

I believe this has to do with reading the pathways to the GDB.  It is important to note that with in the second GDB the target feature class is within a feature dataset.  My arc version is 10.2 if this matters.

```
import arcpy
import os
import traceback

#Set up workspace
outworkspace = "C:\\Users\\bjbart\\Desktop\\Marathon_Loading\\SURVEY_POINTS_V10_1.gdb"
workspace = "C:\\Users\\bjbart\\Desktop\\Marathon_Loading\\out.gdb"

arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

#loops through the first GDB 
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in featureclasses:

    shp_file = fc
    print fc


    if shp_file == "BEND":
        arcpy.Append_management(os.path.join(workspace, "shp_file"), "C:\\Users\\bjbart\\Desktop\\Marathon_Loading\\SURVEY_POINTS_V10_1.gdb\\PIPE_FEATURE\\BEND", "NO_TEST", "","")

        print('BEND File Has Been Appended To Target Database')

    else: print('Error shape file did not get read')'
```

Answer (score 3):

For the script shown here as-is, I think the first error is located in the way we've passed our input dataset parameter to the arcpy.Append_management() tool. It appears that we are attempting to append a feature class called "shp_file" rather than passing the string variable called *shp_file*, which you have created a few lines above.

For this issue, maybe do the following? Please note the removal of quotes on *shp_file*:

```
if shp_file == "BEND":
        arcpy.Append_management(os.path.join(workspace, shp_file), "C:\\Users\\bjbart\\Desktop\\Marathon_Loading\\SURVEY_POINTS_V10_1.gdb\\PIPE_FEATURE\\BEND", "NO_TEST", "","")
```

Good luck here - after this first feature class is appended successfully you could create additional *if* conditions to append the remaining feature classes as needed.